# Centos 7 install a specific version of docker ce

Tags: docker, centos

I'm trying to install a specific version of **Docker CE**, the 20.10.5, to do this I list the versions available with this command:

```
yum list docker-ce-cli --showduplicates | sort -r
```

This is the output:

```
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:20.10.6-3.el7               docker-ce-stable
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:20.10.5-3.el7               docker-ce-stable
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:20.10.4-3.el7               docker-ce-stable
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:20.10.3-3.el7               docker-ce-stable
```

then I specify the version in the installation:

```
sudo yum install docker-ce-20.10.5-3.el7
```

But when I run `docker --version` I still get the 20.10.6 version:

```
Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your `yum list` command is referencing the `docker-ce-cli` package, but your `yum install` command references `docker-ce`. Maybe install `docker-ce-cli` if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are listing the `docker-ce-cli` packages, but then installing `docker-ce`. You'll probably want to install both (and possibly the `containerd.io` as well). See https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/#install-using-the-repository

When checking the version, you can also do `docker version` instead of `docker --version` which will show both the Client and Engine versions, as well as some additional info.

Comment: should docker-ce and docker-ce-cli be the same?

Comment: The documented examples show installing the same version, though its not strictly required as far as I know. It's probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

From your questions looks like you already running docker version. please try this:

1- have you already running the any higher docker version? if yes please uninstall it through yum  and then install docker CE version( which you want to install).

2- if above mentioned does not work then i prefer to install it directly rather than yum repo.